# which tool can i use to export to a target database which has some data already

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration

is there any tool or script i could use to export data from source to target database. The target database has some data already. So the tool has to cater for foreign keys, coming from the source and changes them to point to the correct entity

Comment: Does the structure of Database_A match that of Database_B?

Comment: Yes both structures are the same

Comment: Although you'll probaly find a tool, I advice you do it by your own scripts. Trying to configure a tool you'll have to make the same number of decisions concerning missing / incorrect data handling  as doing it just yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very vague question. You could just use a basic insert statement such as:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Or if the target doesnt have the same columnse use

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

- First send data in a temporary table for each foreign key column, write a script.
- Move the final string to the main table after checking.

good luck